# OSX XAMPP database errors after upgrade

Tags: phpmyadmin

I upgraded my xampp on my mac and am having having issues access the tables any advice to fix it please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems like "something" is wrong with your MySQL database. Any idea what might have gone wrong? In particular, has anything happened to the MySQL data directory (commonly located in `/var/lib/mysql` but with XAMPP it's probably somewhere else), such as you moving a folder in to or out of the data directory or running two MySQL servers at the same time? Are there any hints in the MySQL log? Try running the command `CHECK TABLE login_confirm;` - what is the result?

Before trying anything, you should make a backup.

First, I'd try checking the file level permissions of the MySQL data directory and all subfolders and files. There are probably other ways to determine the path, but I'd log in (through the command line client or phpMyAdmin SQL tab) and run the command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "datadir";`. Go to that folder, then the folder `adenta` within in, and use `ls -l` to check the owner and permissions of all the files match and make sense. On my Debian system, that's owned by user and group `mysql` with permissions `-rw-rw----`. This is the most common reason I can think of for this error, so hopefully it's just a permissions problem.

If the permissions check out okay, you might try the `REPAIR TABLE`. This is only effective on MyISAM, Archive, and CSV table types, so if your tables are InnoDB it won't help. But since we can't even see what table types they're supposed to be, it's worth trying. Run the SQL command `REPAIR TABLE login_confirm;` (or, from the command-line, you can use `mysqlcheck --repair --databases adenta`).

You can try an ALTER TABLE statement. It is best if you know the table type, so try the SQL command `SHOW CREATE TABLE login_confirm` to note if it's MyISAM or InnoDB (or something else). Then run the command `ALTER TABLE login_confirm ENGINE=InnoDB` using the table type you got from the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement (so replace InnoDB with MyISAM if needed).

Failing all that, I think you'll need to dump the table, delete it, and recreate it.

You can export from the command line with `mysqldump adenta login_confirm > export.sql` and import again with `mysql adenta < export.sql`.